# I forgot to calculate for temperature loss during mash in? How will this affect my beer?

Tags: mash, all-grain, batch-sparge

Mash in temperature was supposed to be 152 degrees. I forgot to adjust for temperature loss add simply mixed my grains with 152 degree water. I never calculated the final temperature.

I did the same thing with the batch sparge (poured in 175 degree water).

How will the affect my final product?

Comment: Did you measure the actual mash temp after adding grains to the water?

Comment: I did not. I believe in my setup I should've lost about 9 degrees.

Answer (score 2):

The beer will probably be drier, since I imagine your final mash temperature was in the range of 140-145°F - lower mash temps produce drier beer since there is a greater portion of fermentables. You may also lose body, since the temperature is not optimal for alpha amylase, which produces body enhancing dextrins, and is also close to the protein rest, so proteins may also have been broken down in the mash, causing a thinner body and reduced head.

The lower temperature for batch sparging doesn't really make much difference. In theory, lauter efficiency is slightly higher, but I doubt you'd notice difference in practice.

In future, if you do undershoot your target mash temperature, just stir in some boiling water until the temperature comes up to where you want it. Alternatively, you can decant 1/4 of the mash, bring it to the boil, and then return it to the mash.

Comment: So this won't affect ABV?

Comment: It shouldn't as long as you got conversion.  It takes longer to convert at lower temps so a 90 min, mash would have been ideal.  But even with a 60 min. mash, today's highly modified malts should be able to convert at low temps.